# Is there a limit on the size on an XMLA query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssas-2008, xmla

I have an xmla query that is 10.8 megs, to generate a full SSAS DB with partitions.

After a certain size the editor stops working, I cannot copy paste from/to it, I get memory errors when trying to save and when I try to execute the query, nothing happens.

I have tried on several different machines to rule out a resource issue.

I haven't found anything related to xmla limit that's out there.

Anyone aware of a limit in this area? And if there is, does SQL 2012 remedy it?

Comment: No offense, but I stopped reading after "10.8MB". You're stretching things way beyond their limits here. Start by splitting things up.

Comment: Assuming that you try to execute this from SSMS, I would assume this is a limitation of Management Studio more than Analysis Services itself. You could try using ASCMD for that, see http://msftasprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2005%21Readme%20For%20Command-line%20Utility%20Sample&referringTitle=Home